My F10 F11 F12 is not working when I'm trying to debug in vscode in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm trying to debugging in VSCode and found out my F10 F11 and F12 just increase and decrease the volume and not working as expected even if I press Fn with these buttons it's just not step into the function.
I tested with my windows machine and it's work fine I don't have any problem with these button in windows when debugging.

those keys are generally associated wit media controls in Ubuntu. If you wish to disable them, go to Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Sound and Media and change them there to something which suits your requirements.
